# JS - check if a value defined and not something

Tags: javascript, if-statement, optional-chaining

I want to have a simple check if a value exists but is not something, that something in my case is the string `none`.
in my rest call (which I can't control) I have an inner object that has the status

```
{
   name: "some name",
   internal: { // can be null of an object
      status: "my status" // can be "none" which means I can't find the status
   }
}
```

I want to check for both, but so far I could only come up with

```
a = obj?.internal?.status
if (a && a !== "none") {
  // code
}
```

is there a better way to structure my if statement or my code at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Nullish coalescing operator (`??`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator):

```js
const status = obj?.internal?.status ?? 'none';

if (status !== 'none') {
  // use the status
}
```

Comment: this is exactly what i needed. thank you for remind me the new es11 syntax

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
if((obj?.internal?.status || "none") !== "none") {
    // code
}
```

Or you could use the nullish coalescing operator, as jsejcksn says, to make the condition true in case status is an empty string (`""`).